# Is it possible to save system memory by disabling FishEye System plugins?

Tags: performance

I was wondering if it is safe to disable Atlassian FishEye system plugins I believe, that I don't need?

It says this under plugin management:

> These plugins are integral parts of your FishEye system. They cannot be uninstalled. Disabling or removing them will have serious effects, and may render FishEye inoperable. Do not make changes here unless instructed by Atlassian Support.

Let's say I disable Crudible plugins because I don't use Crudible? Do I gain any performance by disabling them? Is it safe to disable these?

Comment: from the message, I would say no, not without compelling need. how much ram does Task manager report the process using (private Workingset)?

Comment: VIRT 1942m RES 694m SHR 27m